# getting the inner corner angle

Tags: java

I have four points that make concave quad:

a(3 , 11)

b(11 , 9)

c(18 , 10)

d(8 , 1)

[image]

now i wanna get the inner angle of the (b) corner in degrees.
note: the inner angle is greater than 180 degree.

Comment: That would be better suited for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In the `Math` library you can find sine, cosine, tangents, and their inverses. Start with that and see if you can post some code, and we'll help you further... :)

Comment: i know that dear iamnotmaynard, but how can i get a, b, c

Comment: That was a hint to go with vikingsteve's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is to use inner product and cross product , the inner product can be calculated using the 4 points of the two vectors ( a->b , b->c) and using the inner product formula

```
<ab,bc> = |ab|*|bc|* cos (abc)
cos(abc) =  |ab|*|bc| / <ab,bc>
```

this is not enough to allocate the angel uniquely since an angle and its complement has the same cos but has different sins , and here is where the cross product comes to solve the problem

```
ab * bc = |ab|*|bc| * sin(abc)
```

the left part can be calculated using ending points coordinates so you can calculate the sin , once sin and cos is calculated you can specify the angel appropriately .

Comment: dear Yamen, you ignored d point again, and i said before that i cant ignore it.

Comment: the d point doesn't contribute in constructing the abc angle at all you can remove it with affecting the angle you are trying to calculate

Comment: :) ok, but how to determine where is the inner corner if i removed d point.

Answer (score 0):

Point d is just a distraction here. Consider the (abc) triangle:

- It is easy to determine the length of ab, bc and ca from the coordinates.
- you can then determine the (ab, bc) internal angle with sin, cos or tan
- the angle you look for is 360 minus the (ab, bc) internal angle.

Comment: if i ignored (d) point i can't determine where is the inner corner, isn't that?

Comment: Point d is irrelevant - it could be anywhere else without affecting the angle you are looking for.